# Unity URP VolumeComponent Could Not Be Found & Cannot Convert From Vignette To Volume Profile

Tags: unity-game-engine, post-processing, urp

I'm trying to create an animated vignette, but I am unable to reference it in code. On my script attached to the Global Volume, I wrote:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;

public class DyingFade : MonoBehaviour
{
public Volume vol;
public Vignette vig;

void Start()
{
    Vignette tempVig;
    if(vol.profile.TryGet<Vignette>(out tempVig))
    {
        vig = tempVig;
    }
}
}
```

I am getting the following two Errors, specifically at the TryGet statement:

```
The type or namespace name 'VolumeComponent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type 'UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.Vignette' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'VolumeProfile.TryGet<T>(out T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.Vignette' to 'UnityEngine.Rendering.VolumeComponent'.
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who has the same error, I had to uninstall and reinstall the URP Package, and it worked.